# Fast way to extract tokens from scala string

Tags: regex, string, scala

Given a scala string which has a collection of key-value pairs (with the order of type of key-value pair not fixed, number of key-value pairs not fixed):

```
val s = "key1: val1, key2: (val2.1, val2.2, val2.3), key3: (), key4: val4"
```

I need to pull these out into an immutable map like:

```
Map("key1" -> "val1",
  "key2" -> "(val2.1, val2.2, val2.3)",
  "key3" -> "()",
  "key4" -> "val4")
```

I've tried this:

```
val kvMap = s.split(", ").map(_.split(": ")).map(t => t(0) -> t(1)).toMap
```

but this failed because the same delimiter(comma) is used in brackets and between the key-value pairs.

I could do it using a stack using iteration but want to avoid that.

I've also tried to write a regex that could help me do this but could get it working only for 1 pair:

```
scala>  val MyPattern = "([^=]*):(.*)".r
Pattern: scala.util.matching.Regex = ([^=]*):(.*)
                           ^
scala> val MyPattern(k, v) = "key: value"
k: String = key
v: String = " value"
```

I'm looking for a functional way to do this operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your key value pairs do not have nested parentheses, you may use a regex to split with commas + space that are not followed with any characters other than `(` and `)` up to a `)`:

```
""", (?![^()]*\))""".r
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sP6gZ7/1)

**Explanation**:

- `,`  - match a comma and a space after it only if ...
- `(?![^()]*\))` - not followed with non-`)` and non-`)` (0 or more times) followed with a literal `)` (that is, if not followed with something + `)`).

If you want to try with a matching approach:

```
"""([^=:]*):\s*(.*?),?\s*(?=$|\w+:)""".r
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/sP6gZ7/2)

**Details**:

- `([^=:]*)` - Group 1 capturing 0+ characters other than `=` and `:` (perhaps, a `*` should be replaced with `+` since the keys cannot be empty)
- `:\s*` - a colon with 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?),?\s*` - any characters but a newline as few as possible (Group 2,  `(.*?)`) that are followed with an optional `,` and 0+ whitespaces ...
- `(?=$|\w+:)` - that are followed either with the end of string or 1+ word characters and a colon.

Comment: Perfect! This is awesome!